# Problema com update Trigger PLPGSQL

Tags: postgresql, funções, sql-update, trigger, plpgsql

Tenho uma [trigger](/questions/tagged/trigger) para uma auditoria de estoque, o  [insert](/questions/tagged/insert) dela funciona, mas o [update](/questions/tagged/update) não, ou ele não altera nada ou altera todos os registros com o mesmo codigo de item. Como posso ajustar essa parte da [where](/questions/tagged/where) do [update](/questions/tagged/update) para so alterar o ultimo registro que foi editado?

```
tabelas
    **Estoques**
    id
    id_produto
    id_departamento
    saldo
    data
    hora
    prefixoproduto

**estoque_movimento**
id
id_departamento
entrada
saida
data
hora
prefixoproduto


   CREATE TRIGGER t_auditoria_estoque
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON pcp.estoques
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE auditoria_estoque();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditoria_estoque() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        INSERT INTO pcp.estoque_movimento (id_departamento,entrada,data,hora,prefixoproduto)
        VALUES (new.id_departamento,new.saldo,current_date,current_time,new.prefixoproduto);
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
            IF new.saldo <> old.saldo
            THEN
                UPDATE pcp.estoque_movimento 
                SET entrada = NEW.saldo 
                where prefixoproduto = NEW.prefixoproduto
                and id=old.id;
                RETURN NEW;
            END IF;
    END IF;
    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Já tentei mudar pra old.id ou new.id e mas não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Por favor especifique a chave primária das suas tabelas:

Talvez o codigo abaixo te atenda.

```
UPDATE pcp.estoque_movimento As T
   SET T.entrada = NEW.saldo 
 Where T.prefixoproduto = NEW.prefixoproduto
   and T.id = NEW.id
   and T.id_departamento = NEW.id_departamento;
```

Comment: Ricardo então a chave primaria dos dois são a ID, eles não tem nenhum vinculo especifico, Eu consegui fazer funcionar de uma forma porém não sei se está certo porque ela só funcionou quando deletei todo os dados das duas tabelas.

Comment: ```
BEGIN
 IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
  INSERT INTO pcp.estoque_movimento (id_departamento,entrada,data,hora,prefixoproduto)
  VALUES (new.id_departamento,new.saldo,current_date,current_time,new.prefixoproduto);
  RETURN NEW;
 ELSE
   IF new.saldo <> old.saldo
   THEN
    UPDATE pcp.estoque_movimento 
    SET entrada = NEW.saldo 
    where prefixoproduto = NEW.prefixoproduto
    and id=old.id;
    RETURN NEW;
   END IF;
    END IF;
 
END;
```

Comment: seu problema ainda continua?